# SQL buscar los registros que coincidan con un campo maximo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
factura movimiento estado usuario comp
X0001    1         P      A1      1
X0001    2         P      A1      1
X0001    3         C      A1      1
X0005    1         P      A4      1
X0005    2         P      A2      1
X0006    1         C      A1      1
X0006    2         C      A3      1
X0006    3         C      A3      1
X0006    4         C      A4      1
X0007    1         P      A2      1
```

Y quiero encontrar los registros donde el campo movimiento sea el máximo, es decir:

```
X0001    3    C    A1    1
X0005    2    P    A2    1
X0006    4    C    A4    1
X0007    1    P    A2    1
```

He realizado la siguiente consulta

```
Select Max(movimiento) as Movimiento, factura from tablafacturas where comp = '1'
```

y me muestra

```
X0001   3
X0005   2
X0006   4
X0007   1
```

Pero necesito que me muestre todos los demas campos.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no le añades los campos al SELECT? Pues, le estás diciendo que el max(movimiento) y factura... pues dile que también los otros campos

Comment: Porque si le añado los otros campos no funciona

Comment: Para la próxima, "no funciona" no describe ningún error. Y, si ya lo habías probado, eso iba en la pregunta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con una subconsulta, de esta forma:

```
SELECT
    factura, movimiento, estado, usuario, comp
FROM
    tablafacturas t1
WHERE
    movimiento = (SELECT MAX(movimento) FROM tablafacturas t2 WHERE t2.factura = t1.factura GROUP BY factura)
```

Comment: Ok funciona perfecto